# Embedded Google translate bypasses <br/> tag

Tags: html, google-translate

I am developing a website with embedded Google translate option.
When a user changes language the translator bypasses `<br/>` and shows the translated text without paragraphs.
The original text in HTML has a line break and without the translation the layout is as it should be, but when translating `<br/>` seems to not exist.

How can I write the correct code for `<br/>` to work with embedded translator?

For instance: I have a simple text in HTML like:`hello world!<br/> Hello Google translator<br/>` etc.

- without translation:

Hello world!
 Hello Google translator

- with translation:

Hello world! Hello Google translator

Comment: do you mean your page content gets translated? If so, maybe `<br/>` ends up somewhere different in the translated text. Have a look at the `HTML` source after translation, and see if you can find `<br/>` tag at all.

Comment: can we see some code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: If you're using `<br>` tags to denote paragraphs, you should really be using `<p>`aragraph tags.

Comment: because i have some css style in an outer <p> when i try to add an inner <p> tag the style goes wrong ! is there an alternative choice?although i understand that <br/> is not the perfect choice to making paragraphs

Comment: Add a `.class` to the outer `<p>` and your CSS. Then you can use `<p>`s on the inside.

Comment: Got the same issue, anyone know if Goggle is going to fix this?

Comment: I noticed it also seems to kill any hovers you have on the page.